# Creating user status mode in WordPress

Tags: php, post-meta, user-meta

A few days ago I came across a site. The site had a status where a user could post their status about that post. There were five modes:

1. I've seen this anime
2. I'm watching this anime
3. See this in the future
4. I don't see it for now
5. I don't see

then wrote the number of each mode next to the options.
I wanted to run this kind of practice (because I just started programming).
I created the HTML structure and sent the ID of that post and the status of the user status by Ajax to the server.
but I have a problem with saving the user status in WordPress. Now I don't know if it should be saved as meta-post or meta-user.